# Why is htmlentities not working in my Autosdb code?

Tags: php, html, sql

All I am trying to do is escape html injection into my input text boxes. Am I not using htmlentities correctly?

**Code**:

```html
<?php
   require_once "pdo.php";
   // Demand a GET parameter
   if ( ! isset($_GET['name']) || strlen($_GET['name']) < 1  ) {
       die('Name parameter missing');
   } else {
       $username = $_GET['name'];
   }

   // If the user requested logout go back to index.php
   if ( isset($_POST['logout']) ) {
       header('Location: index.php');
       return;
   }

   $year = isset($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year'] : '';
   $mileage = isset($_POST['mileage']) ? $_POST['mileage'] : '';
   $make = isset($_POST['make']) ? $_POST['make'] : '';

   $failure = false;
   $success = false;

   if ( isset($_POST['make']) && isset($_POST['year']) 
        && isset($_POST['mileage'])) {
       //$year = $_POST['year'];
       //$mileage = $_POST['mileage'];
       //$make = $_POST['make'];
       if ( strlen($make) < 1){
           $failure = "Make is Required";
       } else {       
           if (is_numeric($year) and is_numeric($mileage) ){
               error_log("year is a number ".$_POST['year']);        
               error_log("Mileage is a number ".$_POST['mileage']);
               $sql = "INSERT INTO autos (make, year, mileage) 
                 VALUES (:make, :year, :mileage)";

               $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
               $stmt->execute(array(
               ':make' => $make,
               ':year' => $year,
               ':mileage' => $mileage));
               $success = "Record Inserted";      
           } else {
               $failure = "Mileage and Year must be numeric";
               error_log("year or mileage is not a number year=".$_POST['year']);        
               error_log("Mileage or year is not a number mileage=".$_POST['mileage']);
           }
       }
   }

   if ( isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['auto_id']) ) {
       $sql = "DELETE FROM autos WHERE auto_id = :zip";

       $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->execute(array(':zip' => $_POST['auto_id']));
   }

   $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT make, year, mileage, auto_id FROM autos");
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Douglas Osborne's Automobile Tracker</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border="0">
      <?php
         foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
             echo "<tr><td>";
             echo($row['year']);
             echo(" /");
             echo("</td><td>");
             echo($row['make']);
             echo("</td><td>");
             echo($row['mileage']);
             echo(" miles");
             echo("</td><td>");
             echo('<form method="post"><input type="hidden" ');
             echo('name="auto_id" value="'.$row['auto_id'].'">'."\n");
             echo('<input type="submit" value="Del" name="delete">');
             echo("\n</form>\n");
             echo("</td></tr>\n");
         }



         ?>
      <body>
         <div class="container">
            <h1> 
               <?php
                  if ( isset($_REQUEST['name']) ) {
                      echo "<p>Tracking Autos for ";
                      echo htmlentities($_REQUEST['name']);
                      echo "</p>\n";
                  }
                  ?>
            </h1>
            <p>
               <?php
                  // Note triple not equals and think how badly double
                  // not equals would work here...
                  if ( $failure !== false ) {
                      // Look closely at the use of single and double quotes
                      echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($failure)."</p>\n");
                  }
                  if ( $success !== false ) {
                      // Look closely at the use of single and double quotes
                      echo('<p style="color: green;">'.htmlentities($success)."</p>\n");
                  }
                  ?>
            </p>
            <form method="post">
               <p>Make:
                  <input type="text" name="make" size="60" value="<?= htmlentities($make) ?>"/>
               </p>
               <p>Year:
                  <input type="text" name="year" value="<?= htmlentities($year) ?>"/>
               </p>
               <p>Mileage:
                  <input type="text" name="mileage" value="<?= htmlentities($mileage) ?>"/>
               </p>
               <input type="submit" value="Add">
               <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
            </form>
            <h2>Automobiles</h2>
            <ul>
               <p>
            </ul>
         </div>
</html>
```

Output wont escape  see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, `htmlentities` seems to work as intended, the "bad" characters such as < or > are replaced in the source code by &lt; and &gt;, so that the html code is syntaxically correct. Thus, the < or > are visible in the input field. That's the normal behavior. If you want to remove html tags, you are wrong with `htmlentities`, and you will have to use `strip_tags` instead

Comment: Thanks for replying. strip_tags doesn't work because it would remove letters inside of the tags. I was trying to have the input displayed on my page with tags still in it. Currently if the user inserts a <b>, for example input =  su<b>uru, its showing up as "su**uru**" with the last characters "uru" in bold. I want it to display as "su<b>uru" to avoid html injection. Thanks again for your input

Comment: you are wrong, `strip_tags` does not remove the content of the tag, please refer to php manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php. That's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for replying again. I understand that you think I'm wrong but I implemented strip_tags and did not get the result I desire. When the user enters "Su<b>uru" after the strip_tags function is ran the output is "Suuru". I need the output to be stored the same as the input without changing the content to bold "Su<b>uru". Thanks again for all your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding htmlspecialchars to (make) gave me the result I was looking for. Thanks for anyone's attempt to help me.